# How to upload Olympus native images and videos to Google Photos?

Tags: python, api, photo, gdata

I am trying to upload images and videos from my Olympus camera to Google Photos using the Google gdata photos API.
When I specify contentType='image/jpeg' it uploads to Google Photos beautifully.

However, I am failing to upload the .ORF and .MTS files. The code excerpt is as below:

```
gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(source=user_agent,
                                           email=email,
                                           additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})
album = gd_client.InsertAlbum( title=d, summary=d, access='private')
gd_client.InsertPhoto(album, picasa_photo, localPath, content_type=contentType)
```

For example, when I change contentType to 'image/x-olympus-orf' , it fails to upload. The error is:

```
(400, 'Bad Request', 'Not a valid image.')
```

Based on the [API doc](https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.photos.service.html#PhotosService), the content_type parameter is optional. I tried by removing it and that didn't help either. 
Same result is seen for the MTS video files.

Answer (score 0):

Google Photos is not a general file storage space, like Google Drive. It only accepts known image types that can be displayed in a browser - PNG, JPG, GIF, and BMP. If you look at the documentation page you linked in your question and scroll down to `InsertPhoto`, it tells you which filetypes are acceptable. Since it doesn't understand the encoding of the proprietary Olympus filetypes you're trying to upload, it rejects them - the error message is pretty self-explanatory. You'll need to convert your files into an acceptable filetype before uploading.

Comment: Before they introduced Google Photos, they had Picasaweb and I was able to upload those files. Picasaweb would show these formats. Google Photos rejects them.
Further it was supposed to have [better RAW support](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RonaldWotzlaw/posts/MuCdS9Wx7SM), isn't it?